# Find a triplet that sum to a given value in an array and each number can be repeated multiple times. Each pair should be unique in the output

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, time-complexity

I know how to handle the case when there are no duplicate number in the array. It would start by sorting the array and then handling the problem as if it were the standard 2 sum problem.

I am not sure what would be the best approach when there are duplicates in the given array. I could first remove all the duplicate and proceed. Can someone please suggest me a better way here. 
Thanks.

Comment: One common way to remove duplicates is to convert the array to a set, which does not contain duplicates by definition.

Comment: On the other hand, I don't think it really matters for your suggested algorithm whether the array contains duplicates.